# Trying to fetch data from self signed server using swift, for iOS app developement

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire

first I tried info.plist way, to make my site an exception using

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>service.medimetry.dev</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Still shows the error "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
After tried like 5 different variants of upper code, i started looking for another angle. 
I tried swiftHTTP way to bypass SSL Authentication using this code

```
func getAllReminders () {
    do {
        let opt = try HTTP.GET("https://service.medimetry.dev/api/v2/reminders")
        var attempted = false
        opt.auth = { challenge in
            if !attempted {
                attempted = true
                return URLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust)
            }
            return nil
        }

        opt.start { response in
            if let err = response.error {
                print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return //also notify app of failure as needed
            }
            print("opt finished: \(response.description)")

            print("Response Loggin starts >>>")
            print(response.data)
            print("<<< Response Loggin ends")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I got this error '"challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust" do not match available overloads' tried finding a way around, just couldn't.

then google all packages for http and found Alamofire
also had same issue, tried googling around and found this write this code

```
func getAllReminders () {
    defaultManager.request("https://service.medimetry.dev/api/v2/reminders").responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
        }

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        }
    }
}

let defaultManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "127.0.0.1:443": .disableEvaluation,
        "service.medimetry.dev:443": .disableEvaluation,
        "https://service.medimetry.dev:443": .disableEvaluation,
        "127.0.0.1:80": .disableEvaluation,
        "service.medimetry.dev:80": .disableEvaluation,
        "https://service.medimetry.dev:80": .disableEvaluation,
        ]

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    return Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
}()
```

but again this response
2017-08-03 16:29:34.369747+0530 Reminders System[5364:433698] [] nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9812]
2017-08-03 16:29:34.369 Reminders System[5364:433712] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
Request: Optional(https://service.medimetry.dev/api/v2/reminders)
Response: nil
Result: FAILURE
Data:

I have spent hours on this issue, please tell me what I am doing wrong. any fix in above mentioned code, or any other way around, while going in production i will have all the right servers but just need a way around in debug mode.
In alamofire i have tried [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/941). Also if there is easy way using justHTTP pod.
For server i am using laravel valet with secure flag on.

Comment: try adding <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/> to your plist

Comment: it would be inside the dict where other keys are

Comment: Tried already didn't worked, will try one more timing. Also is this method forced to work on swift native functions or even using pods.

Comment: anything in your proj that deals with internet including pods

Comment: this is my podfile `platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Reminders System' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Reminders System
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
` except that, this is just core project i am firing above mentioned method from viewDidLoad itself

Comment: I use only these 3 keys to connect to self signed certificate and it works fine - <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.1</string>

Comment: And i am using alamofire itself and with .disableEvaluation as you have done

Comment: So nothing wrong in your pods

Comment: Ok, let me try one more time with just 3 keys

Comment: `Request: Optional(https://service.medimetry.dev/api/v2/reminders)
Response: nil
Result: FAILURE
Data: ` still this response, Please also tell me if there is any problem with my alamofire function , i couldn't figure out the right way so i put all i can think off

Comment: Ok so your 1 error is gone and you are able to connect to server. now its about response. What  parameters are to be passed in request?

Comment: no parameters, actually, in chrome it gives proper json output

Comment: Is it a post or GET request. Also is json or xml?

Comment: it is GET request, returns JSON string

Comment: is it possible that i am running in emulator and my site being a localhost site, have a problem with it?

Comment: Localhost as in on the same system as your emulator is?

Comment: yes, definitely.

Comment: Then use it by IP and should work.

Comment: Can you try opening the same URL in simulator browser and see if its some other connectivity issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add only these keys in your plist

```
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/> 
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key> <true/> 
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key> <string>TLSv1.1</string>
```

And it should work for self signed certificate

Comment: Didn't worked, also i am able to open page in emulator's browser.

Comment: Also it prompted me of SSL certificate

Comment: Can you paste the url here?

Comment: If you are using https://service.medimetry.dev/api/v2/reminders, it is not a localhost or an IP URL. Its external DNS and if we are taking exception for this URL, local url won't work

Comment: But this is not localhost :)

Comment: also i added this url to exception list of plist and alamofire serverTrustPolicies

Comment: actually i have both service.medimetry.dev as well as service.medimetry.in, first i tried .dev and then .in.  .dev is localhost. I thought you wanted to see the response so i sent this

Comment: hey since both are mapped to a DNS or a domain, none of them are localhost. and they are accessible from internet as i can access them. :)

Comment: Trying at my end. give me 10 mins

Comment: ok, didn't knew that. thanks, .in is accessible from internet. .dev is not

Comment: this is my code, if you like to have a look at it https://github.com/alvin4frnds/Reminders-App/blob/master/Reminders%20System/HttpRequest.swift

Comment: Ok so didnt work for me. can you try to just add <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict> and see if it works.

Comment: Nope, still failure.